# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this error when i am updating my subject table. Please let me know the error solution.

```
// Perform Update
$id = mysql_prep($_GET['subj']);
$menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST['menu_name']);
$position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
$visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);

$query = "UPDATE subjects SET 
            menu_name ='{$menu_name}', 
            position ={$position}, 
            visible ={$visible} 
        WHERE id ={$id}";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
    // Success
    $message = "The subject was successfully updated.";
} else {
    // Failed
    $message = "The subject update failed.";
    $message .= "<br />". mysql_error();
}
```

EDIT:

```
function mysql_prep($value){
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();    
    $new_enough_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");//i.e. PHP version >=4.3.0 or not

    if($new_enough_php){
        if($magic_quotes_active){
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
    else{
        if(!$magic_quotes_active){
            $value = addslashes($value);
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Show the query after the variables are interpolated. Also the the code for `mysql_prep()`

Comment: [generic `mysql` is deprecated comment here]

Comment: Use mysqli or pdo, and there are like 50 questions under "related" that share the exact same title? Did you check those?

Comment: function mysql_prep($value){
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");//i.e. PHP version >=4.3.0 or not
    if($new_enough_php){
        if($magic_quotes_active){$value = stripslashes($value);}
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
    else{
        if(!$magic_quotes_active){$value = addslashes($value);}
    }
    return $value;
}

Comment: Show us the sql that is being executed after the variables are placed inside. Before: `$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);` type `exit($query);` and it will output the query to the screen.

Comment: What does `echo $query;` show you?

Comment: You should NOT be writing your own mysql functions. And especially not compensating for obsolete/dinosaur-age PHP versions. You should be using PDO or mysqli to start with.

Comment: ^ ElePHPants hadn't even evolved then... possibly TriceraPHPtops?

Comment: We cannot provide a definitive answer until we see the SQL that is being executed.

Comment: UPDATE subjects SET menu_name ='Mobiles & Tablet', position =1, visible =1 WHERE id =  
//this is what it shows

Comment: @ManojMajumdar: There's your problem.  There's no ID value.

Comment: Thanks I got this, I have to now look in my code for why I am not getting the ID value.

Comment: <form action="edit_subject.php?subj=<?php echo urlencode($sel_subject['id']); ?>" method="post">

// Here is the form submission where subject id should be shown in the url, but it doesn,t. I could not understand why it is not outputting the id, whereas $sel_subject['menu_name'] outputs the menu_name of the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `$id` is not set properly.  Probably it is an empty string.  Or maybe it has some other cruft in it, like a comma, quote, parenthesis.  Best course is to show it before executing the query.

Answer (score -1):

The apostrophes are near the $_POST for menu name.  Notice that there are none elsewhere in the call.  The apostrophes imply literal, but the curly brackets imply evaluated.

Comment: Do you mean this `'{$menu_name}'`?  The `$menu_name` variable is inside curly brackets, so it's evaluated.  The apostrophes are part of the string.

Comment: The error is citing the emptiness between the apostrophes.

Comment: "emptiness"?  Which line are you referring to?

Comment: The error message, that is the headline of the question, ends with ''.  So, there are apostrophes being printed with no data between them.  The core of the actual problem will lie with why there is no data where the programmer expected there to be some.

Comment: The apostrophes are actually part of the error message.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7884522